# Can I somehow use if statement in switch to add more cases?

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm trying to write a *"switch"* statement but I have strictly defined case and I want to use as little code as I can. So as I was wondering how to do it one thought came to my mind, is it possible to add *"if"* statement in *"switch"* so if this *"if"* statement is true to add more cases to my *"switch"*. For example:

```
switch(myVar) {
    case 1: 
        return 'Your variable is 1';
    case 2: 
        return 'Your variable is 2';
    if(yourVar && yourVar === true) {
        case 3: return 'Your variable is 3';
    }
    default: return 0;
}
```

P.S. The real scenario I am using is way more complicated and the code is really long so any sugestions are welcomed if they fit the use case.

Comment: What if you close your `switch(myVar)` at the end of `case2` then use if statement in order to decide wether to define another `switch` or not?

Comment: No it's not possible. Catch those with special rules in default and then use if conditions.

Comment: For future users to know, it would be good if you accept the answer that best solve your original question, as it is not a bad question, even if you found another way by reconstruct your initial code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this

```js
function test(myVar, yourVar) {

  switch(myVar) {
    case 1: return '1';
    case 2: return '2';

    default:
      // as requested in a comment, add yourVar to myVar
      if(myVar != undefined && yourVar != undefined) return myVar + yourVar;

      return '0';
  }
}

alert(test(2));
alert(test(3));
alert(test(3,5));
alert(test(3,0));
```

Comment: It may actually work with this but I am not sure if this is the best way. Still, thank you for your suggestion, I will consider it.

Comment: Your suggestion would not work for me because it is something I should draw on a website. More specific, if the condition for "yourVar === true" I should draw dropdown in the website with myVar + yourVar number of elements, if it is false I should not draw the "yourVar" elements. I'm sorry if I am not clear enough.

Comment: @GeorgePandurov I updated my first sample. Does that logic work for you?

Comment: I found a way to simplify my code a little and now it will work. Thanks for your fast replies and btw I didn't downvote you but for some reason in SO if you don't have 15 points and upvote someone's coment it downvotes it.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but note that some people have religious objections to the `switch (true)` idiom.

Comment: Took that alternative out.

Comment: I am accepting your answer as it is possible to solve my problem by moving the condition in the default case for people who may come across the same problem.

PS: Sorry I haven't accepted it sooner but I remember way back clicking on the icon, maybe something went wrong

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you move your logic a bit. You can omit the [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) statement, because you ends the function with [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return).

```
switch(true) {
    case myVar === 1:
        return 'Your variable is 1';
    case myVar === 2:
        return 'Your variable is 2';
    case yourVar:
        return 'Your variable is 3';
    default:
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, actually in my real project code there is no break I just accidentally placed it here (I will fix it now). About your suggestion I will think about it and see if I would be able to use it in my case.

Comment: Just to add something, actually in my project I had to check the value and not if it is true or false so your suggestion couldn't help me.

Comment: the comparison is primary not between the switch and case, but first at the case place and then with true (switch), so you can anything compare at the case place and the compare it with the switch place. maybe it is better if you add some real problem.

Comment: I just saw a new comment here and decided to add my opinion for your comment because I have a little free time. About my problem I fixed it by reworking my logic(as someone have adviced me) so at the end I didn't use such strange switch statement :)

Answer (score 2):

Move the test inside the case, and fall through if it fails:

```
switch(myVar) {
  case 1: 
    return 'Your variable is 1';
  case 2: 
    return 'Your variable is 2';
  case 3:
    if (yourVar) return 'Your variable is 3';
    /* fall through */
  default: 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
switch(myVar) {
    case 1: 
        return 'Your variable is 1';
    case 2: 
        return 'Your variable is 2';
    case 3: 
      if(yourVar && yourVar === true) {
        return 'Your variable is 3';
      }else{
        return 0:
        }
    default: return 0;
}
```